# Custom UL Structure for JQuery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-autocomplete

JQuery Autocomplete shows results in form of a UL and items as its LI elements. I have a tree structure of elements which is 2 levels deep and have expand and collapse functionality. It looks something like this:

[image]

This structure is created from a JSON array of this format:

```
[
{
    "scope": "1",
    "active": "true",
    "id": "T8",
    "label": "Last Close Price",
    "type": "TECHNICAL",
    "value": "Last Close Price",
    "group": "Price"
},
{
    "scope": "1",
    "active": "true",
    "id": "T32",
    "label": "Open Price",
    "type": "TECHNICAL",
    "value": "Open Price",
    "group": "Price"
}]
```

and its html structure is something like this:

```
<ul><li><a href="#">TECHNICAL</a>
        <ul><li><a href="#">Price</a>
                <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Now I want to implement JQuery UI autocomplete on this array and show filtered results in the same array.

But by looking at the Documentation, I couldn't find anything which can modify the results of JQuery Autocomplete to this level. Most people just want to modify the html of individual LI elements, here I want to create deep level nesting of UL elements to form the tree structure. I have already written a function which creates this tree but where to put it in Autocomplete and how to get the keyboard keys functioning (i.e. select element with arrow keys) is the question.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think customization on such a level is possible with the jquery ui autocomplete plugin !

Comment: Its javascript, open and editable code, impossible doesn't be the right word for this kind of language.

Comment: Well, in that case you should develop your new autocomplete plugin that provides such a high level of customization and after all **"impossible doesn't be the right word for this kind of language !!!"**

Comment: You seem to be offended. Sorry for that. Am still looking for the answer. and if I don't find any alternative, developing it myself is plan B.